# Как отдать на фрон json нужного вида?

Tags: php, json

Есть таблица msql "categories"

[image: msql]

Нужно вивести инфу в json для отправки на фронт, делаю так

```
require_once 'connection.php'; 
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Categories";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $rows[] = array(
      "id" => $row['id'],
      "name" => $row['name']);
     }

$json = json_encode($rows);


echo $json;

mysqli_close($link);
```

Получаю:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Apple"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Samsung"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Htc"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Lenovo"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Mi"
    }
]
```

а мне нужно такого вида

```
{
"categories" : [ //название таблици
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Apple"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Samsung"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Htc"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Lenovo"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Mi"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете(предпочтительно) изменить нужным образом структуру:

```
$json = json_encode(array('categories' => $rows));
```

Либо вручную исправить уже сериализованные данные(не рекомендуется):

```
$json = <<<JSON
{
  "categories": $json
}
JSON;
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло